# Correct way to expire a fragment cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

In the view for `Reports#index`, I cache a fragment like this:

```
- cache("#{@country}-#{@category}-#{@benchmark}-#{@status}") do
```

*Note that those four variables are strings, not model objects, so they will not expire automatically on touch.*

To expire every copy of this cache, do I have to call `expire_fragment` for every string that could be generated by cocacenating possible values for `@country`, `@category`, `@benchmark` and `@status`? Or will `expire_fragment reports_path` do the trick?

Sorry the API docs aren't crystal clear on this and it's not the type of thing that's easily, robustly tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would indeed need to expire each fragment from individually - there is no way in general to expire a range of keys (I think memorystore supports expiry by regexp but I don't think anyone uses that in production).

You may be better off choosing your cache keys so that they change when the underlying data has changed.